# Page transition animations with Angular 2.0 router and component interface promises

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

In Angular 1.x we can use ngAnimate to detect when we are leaving or entering a particular route. Furthermore we are able to apply behaviors to them:

```
animateApp.animation('.myElement', function(){

    return {

        enter : function(element, done) {
            //Do something on enter
        },

        leave : function(element, done) {
            //Do something on leave
        }
    };

)};
```

Resulting in a product like this: http://embed.plnkr.co/uW4v9T/preview

I would like to do something similar with Angular 2.0 and I feel like I'm pretty close...

So here goes, I've created a simple router in the main application component that controls the navigation between the *home* and *about* components.

```
import { bootstrap, bind, Component, provide, View } from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouteConfig, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router'




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Home Component Start
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Component({
  selector: 'home-cmp'
})

@View({
  template: `
    <h2 class="title">Home Page</h2>
  `
})

class HomeCmp implements OnActivate, onDeactivate{

  onActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log("Home Page - initialized");
  }

  onDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log("Home Page - destroyed");
  }

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Home Component End
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// About Component Start
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Component({
  selector: 'about-cmp'
})

@View({
  template: `
    <h2 class="title">About Page</h2>
  `
})

class AboutCmp implements OnActivate, onDeactivate {

  onActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log("About Page - initialized");
  }

  onDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log("About Page - destroyed");
  }

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// About Component End
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Application Componenent Start
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {{message}}!</h1>
      <a [router-link]="['./HomeCmp']">home</a>
      <a [router-link]="['./AboutCmp']">about</a>
      <hr>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: HomeCmp, as: 'HomeCmp'},
  {path: '/about', component: AboutCmp, as: 'AboutCmp'}
])

export class App {
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Application Componenent End
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'})
])
```

At the moment I am able to capture when the router has instantiated or destroyed a particular component when it moves from one to the next. This is great, but when the the *previous* component is *destroyed* I am not able to apply an *on leave* transition animation before the next component is initialized.

```
class HomeCmp implements OnActivate, onDeactivate{

    onActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        //This works
        TweenMax.fromTo($(".title"), 1, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1});
    }

    onDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        //This get ignored
        TweenMax.fromTo($(".title"), 1, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1});
    }

}
```

It seems like there is a solution to this using promises. Angular.io's API preview they state:

**If onDeactivate returns a promise, the route change will wait until the promise settles.**

and

**If onActivate returns a promise, the route change will wait until the promise settles to instantiate and activate child components.**

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

I am super brand new to promises so I mashed this together into my code which solved the problem of my current component being destroyed on initialization of the next one, but then it *never* gets destroyed, it only creates a new instance of it. Every time I navigate back to it, it will create a new instance resulting in multiple copies.

```
onDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {

    function ani(){
      TweenMax.fromTo($(".title"), 1, {opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0});
    }

    var aniPromise = ani();

    aniPromise.then(function (ani) {
        ani();
    });

}
```

So to recap, the router should be able to wait for the current component to finish it's *business* before destroying it and initializing the next component.

I hope that all makes sense and I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you quoted from the docs, if any of this hooks returns a Promise it will wait until its completed to move to the next one, so you can easily return a Promise that basically does nothing and wait a second (or as many time as you need).

```
 onActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    TweenMax.fromTo($(".title"), 1, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1});
    return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(1), 1000));
  }

  onDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    TweenMax.fromTo($(".title"), 1, {opacity:1}, {opacity: 0});
    return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(1), 1000));
  }
```

Note that I'm returning a Promise which runs a setTimeout. We wait a second to give the animation time enough to be completed.

I don't really like using setTimeouts, so we can use Observables as well, that personally I like the best.

```js
return Rx.Observable.of(true).delay(1000).toPromise();
```

Here I'm passing a random value (true in this case) and delay it a second and finally cast it to Promise. Yes, it ends up being a Promise but I don't use it directly.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pCxVob?p=preview) with an example working (expecting to be what you are looking for).

PS: If sometimes it complains about that it can't find a path to Rx, just keep refreshing until it works (I added Rx.js manually and it's a little heavy for plnkr apprently).

Comment: you're spot on thanks for the quick and comprehensive reply!

Comment: Great reply! I'm wondering if there is a way to "overlap" the animations. It looks to me that it wont be that easy as the first component should be hidden(deactivated) to show(activate) the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't find "ComponentInstruction". Is that still part of Angular 2 api?

Comment: @Jim correct, it was [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127746/loggedinoutlet-angular2-authentication-router-v3-0-0-alpha8-where-is-compone).

Answer (score 9):

**Angular 2 final solution:**

[plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/Vral6cwlaQz27MUQNkVg/)

In a nutshell, we can to use the `@routeAnimation` built-in directive to achieve this. Each of our components representing a child route will be decorated with something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pageone'
  host: { '[@routeAnimation]': 'true' },
  styles: [':host { width: 300px; display: block; position: absolute; }']
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
      state('*', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0}),
        animate('0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)')
      ]),
      transition('* => void',
        animate('0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)', style({
          transform: 'translateX(100%)',
          opacity: 0
        }))
      )
    ])
  ]
})
```

Comment: the `styles: [':host { width: 300px; display: block; position: absolute; }']` bit was much needed, was having difficulties getting mine until I saw this, thanks!

Comment: Instead of using style on every component you can also put this in your css:  `router-outlet + * {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Is it possible to do it without `position: absolute;`? Because absolute position breaks my original styles. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @arouse, might be a little bit difficult to recommend a solution without seeing your code. Perhaps it would help if you wrapped each layout in another div (maybe with relative positioning).

Comment: I think most people have loading/preloading screen that work by add/remove class which won't work with angular because router won't wait that animation