# angular2 component transition animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

How to make page transition animation in angular2 ?

I try this is code but not working

```
@Component({
   selector:'myPagefirstPage', 
})

@View({
   template: `<div  class="view-animate ng-animate" > 
                 <h1>First Page</h1>
              </div>`
```

And I put my animation class in css file like this

```
.view-animate.ng-enter {....}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not certain that animation is implemented at all yet, as of alpha 48. In any case, I would assume you'll have to import ANIMATION_DIRECTIVES or something like that to use them in a given component

Answer (score 4):

As of December 2015, animations are not implemented in Angular 2 beta release, and are due in the final release.

http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2015/12/angular-2-beta.html

> ### What comes next?
>
> We're already hard at work on the set of improvements to move Angular
>   2 to its full and final release.  While we will make many small
>   improvements, the big ones for final are:
>
> 1. Reducing Angular 2's payload size.
> 2. Making the Angular CLI usable end to end throughout the development process.
> 3. Creating a more developer-friendly route definition and link API for the Component Router.
> 4. ***Support for animations.***
> 5. I18n and L10n support.

Edit: Animations are now in - http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/rc2-now-available.html

> ### RC2 Now Available
>
> Today we’re happy to announce that we are shipping Angular 2.0.0-rc2.
>
> This release includes:
>
> 1. Animation Framework
>
> ...

Answer (score 4):

As of beta 15, basic transitions using e.g. `.ng-enter` and `.ng-enter-active` works. Note that you must add the `ng-animate` class to the animated element. See this plunkr for an example http://plnkr.co/edit/WcH3ndMN0HOnK2IwOCev?p=preview

However, note that `ng-leave` is not supported as of now as the DOM node is removed before out animation is done (see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6768)

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using at least Angular 2.0.0-rc2, we can add a transition animation (fadeIn for example) between our components by adding a `div` that wrap our component view like this :

```
<div @fadeIn="'in'">
       ... Component HTML ...
</div>
```

And in your component we have to set the animation `fadeIn` :

```
@Component({
    ...
    animations: [
        trigger('fadeIn', [
            state('*', style({'opacity': '0'})),
            transition('* => in', [animate('800ms linear', style({'opacity': '1'}))])
        ])
    ]
```

[EDIT] an alternative way without using the state is as follow:

```
<div @fadeIn>
       ... Component HTML ...
</div>
```

And the component:

```
@Component({
    ...
    animations: [
        trigger('fadeIn', [
            state('*', style({'opacity': 1})),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({'opacity': 0}),
                animate('800ms linear')
            ])
        ])
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Angular 2 final solution**

As stated by @JeanMel, we can use the `@routeAnimation` built-in directive to achieve this. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077108/1087131) which includes a plunk.

Answer (score 0):

For a page transition, you can rely on a `routeAnimation`

`Animations.ts`

```
import {style, animate, transition, state, trigger} from '@angular/core';

export default [
  trigger('routeAnimation', [
    state('*', style({opacity: 1, height: '100%'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({opacity: 0, height: '100%'}),
      animate(200)
    ]),
    transition('* => void', animate(0, style({opacity: 0, height: '100%'})))
  ])
];
```

Then in your `YourComponent.ts`

```
import animations from './Animations';
@Component({
  ...
  animations: animations
})
export class YourComponent {
  @HostBinding('@routeAnimation') public routeAnimation:void;
  ...
}
```

Optional: This assumes your `routing.ts` file looks like

```
import {RouterModule}  from '@angular/router';
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {YourComponent} from './YourComponent';

export const routing:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {path: "aPath", component: YourComponent}
]);
```