# Route change transition effect

Tags: angular

I am wondering if any of you have implemented Router transition effect in Angular2?

I want to use mostly CSS.

So far I've got rid of states I didn't needed, and added some CSS tricks into my view, to trick user that there is a state change, but this approach will get me nowhere.

What I am looking for specifically, is overlapping animations: one state slides to the left, another slides from the right. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553828/page-transition-animations-with-angular-2-0-router-and-component-interface-promi), but it is not helpful.

Looking for ideas,

thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if you could come up with css and things you have done so far. May be someone else  can help you further.

Comment: @micronyks, my css is a simple class addition on states that leave/enter, using transform and delay

Comment: Okay but at least come up with that so may be someone can think more on it. I have worked with Ui-View state transition effect. So may be I or someone else can help you.

Comment: I have posted an example of this. google should have taken you to my website! http://www.waynehong.com/javascript/angular2-page-transition-animation-example/

Comment: Indeed it is helpful @sdfacre. .