# LoggedInOutlet angular2 authentication - Router v3.0.0-alpha8 - Where is ComponentInstruction?

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router, angular2-router3

I am using code like this to extend RouterOutlet and create app wide authentication and route protection

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ViewContainerRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ComponentInstruction} from '@angular/router';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {RouterOutletMap} from '@angular/router/src/router_outlet_map';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';

import {Authentication} from '../common/authentication.service';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes:any;
  isAuthenticated:boolean;
  //private router: any;

  constructor(public _elementRef: ElementRef, public _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
              public _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string, public authService:Authentication) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
    this.isAuthenticated = authService.isLoggedIn();


    //this.router = _parentRouter;
    /**
     * DEFINE PUBLIC ROUTES
     *
     * The Boolean following each route below denotes whether the route requires authentication to view.
     *
     * Format: key/value pair
     * - key is the /route url "/login", "/signup", etc
     * - value is a boolean true/false
     *    `true` means it's a publicly available route. No authentication required
     *    `false` means it's a protected route which is hidden until user is authenticated
     *
     */
    this.publicRoutes = {
      'login': true,
      'signup': true,
      '404': true
    };
  } // end constructor

  routeIsActive(routePath:string) {
    return this.router.url == routePath;
  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    // let url = instruction.urlPath;
    let url = this.router.url;
    // If the url doesn't match publicRoutes and they are not authenticated...
    if (!this.publicRoutes[url] && !this.isAuthenticated) {
      // todo: redirect to Login, may be there a better way?
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
    return super.activate(instruction);
  }
}
```

Problem is that ComponentInstruction does not exist in the new v3.0.0-alpha8 router, and the super method signature has changed. How do I update this to work in the new router? I cannot find any documentation explaining the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ComponentInstruction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/ComponentInstruction-interface.html) has been deprecated. In the current RC4 version of Angular2, this class has been listed under reouter-deprecated. With RC5 coming in, this package would be dropped.

RouterOutlet has changed a lot over time and to make your class LoggedInRouterOultet work, you have to use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) interface.

You can do something like this:

**Have an injectable service like LoggedInActivator shown here:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LogInService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInActivator implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private loginService: LogInService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

**Add canActivate and map it to LoggedInActivator on component while defining route:**

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInActivator] }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Answer (score 0):

because in new router, it uses [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard)