# How do I extend routerOutlet in angular 2 rc4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
import { ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Directive, ResolvedReflectiveProvider} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet, ActivatedRoute, RouterOutletMap } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class ApplicationRouter extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: Array;
    private parentRouter: Router;
    private router: Router;

    constructor(parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap, location:ViewContainerRef, componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, name: string) {
        super(parentOutletMap, location, componentFactoryResolver, name);
        this.router = _parentRouter;
    }

    activate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) {
        debugger;
       // return super.activate(instruction);
    }

}
```

> I I don't know the types for the super class to be instantiated, the
>   purpose is to move authorization to router level.

Comment: Is there a documentation for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested on extending RouterOutlet for particular reasons or just to add an authentication layer to your routes? For the latter just change your auth class from "extends RouterOutlet" to "implements CanActivate".

An example of "AuthenticationGuard" implementation:

```
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then on your routes file(s) add the "CanActivate" property to the routes you want an access control layer:

```
//route file
...
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: CrisisAdminComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
...
```

Simple as that.

From [angular docs router guards session](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after Angular upgrade to RC4. One of the application components was extending [**RouterOutlet**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html)

**RouterOutlet** has changed a lot over time and to make your class ApplicationRouter work, you need to make use of router guarding by implementing [**CanActivate**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) interface.

Please check my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38497746/2432333) and to read more on router guarding refer [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard).

I hope this helps!